Does the transfer occurring under Article 45, 46 or 49 affect the Right of Access under Article 15.2?
Transfer of personal data from the UK to the US can, at least in theory, occur under Articles 45, 46 and 49.  These all have different requirements.
Article 15 of the GDPR the Right of access includes section 2:

Where personal data are transferred to a third country or to an international organisation, the data subject shall have the right to be informed of the appropriate safeguards pursuant to Article 46 relating to the transfer

This says the data must be provided, and makes no mention of the Article under which the data was transferred.  Article 46 includes a lot of things that one would expect any data transfer agreement to have, such as "binding corporate rules", "standard data protection clauses" and "an approved code of conduct".
If one takes for example the AXA privacy policy which says (page 3):

We will only transfer your personal information to another country or an international organisation outside the United Kingdom or those countries considered “adequate” by the UK regulator (such as those within the European Economic Area or EEA) where we have taken the required steps to ensure that your personal information is protected. Such steps may include placing the party we are transferring information to under contractual obligations to protect it to adequate standards and performing appropriate risk assessments of those transfers

If we assume a transfer occurred under Article 45, such that it was from the UK to the US to an organisation on the Data Privacy Framework List would the data controller be required to provide these standards and obligations in the same way as they would if the transfer had been under Article 46?  If not, what would the data controller have to tell the data subject?  Would the above paragraph be sufficient for an Article 45 transfer?
Note I have asked a separate question about if the above paragraph fulfills the Article 46 rules.

Given that this is about the UK, should the question not be using the UK GDPR (and links thereto)?

Art 15(2) confuses me, this seems to be redundant with the right to information in Art 13(1)(f) / Art 14(1)(f).
